# Angular App issue where buttons have to be clicked twice before state change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using ui-router on an angular app and experiencing a problem where certain buttons using ui-sref have to be clicked twice before it changes state. Just hoping someone else has had this same issue and found a solution.

here is the button html:

```
<button id="continue-btn1" type="button" class="btn btn-reset btn-continue"  ui-sref="appGatewayEditor.suppPay" data-ng-disabled="suppQuestions.$invalid">continue <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>
</button>
```

The router is using nested views like this:

```
 .state('appGatewayEditor.suppPay', {
                url: "/supplemental-payment",
                templateUrl: 'components/appGateway/appGatewayEditor/supplemental/suppPay.html',
                controller: 'supplementalPayCtrl as suppPayCtrl'
            })
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated!!

Comment: Looks to me like it has something to do with your `ng-disabled`. Perhaps it's disabled and the first click enables it?

Comment: Thats's not the problem, I have tried that already.

Comment: The button is in a form, and only gets enabled once the form is valid

Comment: And when you click it first time, is the form valid ?

Comment: Thats correct, the button only becomes enabled after the form is vald

Comment: From the documentation it looks like ui-sref should only be used with anchor tags. I would just ng-click to a function and use $state.go.